# Appcelerator change Content height on a ScrollView

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have a scroll view in my alloy project and I need to add a few views when a button is pressed, but the content height, the scrollable area, is not changing, the bottom content goes away from the view.
This is my Alloy View (.xml) file

```
<Alloy>
  <Window class="container">
    <ScrollView id="MainView" >
      <View id="innerContent" class="rowLayout">
        <Label>Address 1</Label>
        <TextField id="Address1" class="textArea"></TextField> 
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
    <View id="buttonView">
      <Button id="button" onClick="doClick" title="Add New Address Input" top="10" width="100" height="50" />
    </View>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

My styling file (.tss), with all the styles:

```
    ".container": {
        backgroundColor:"white",
        height: Titanium.UI.FILL
    }
    "#MainView": { 
        width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
        height: Titanium.UI.FILL,
        scrollType: "vertical",
        layout: "vertical",
        bottom: "100dp",
        top: "20dp",
        borderColor: "#008000",
        borderWidth: "1px",
        left:"2dp",
        right: "2dp"

    }

    "#buttonView" : {
        height: "50dp",
        width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
        right: "10dp",
        left: "10dp",
        bottom: '8dp',
        borderColor: "#000000",
        borderWidth: "1px"
    }
    ".rowLayout": {
        layout: "vertical"
    }
    ".textArea" : {
        height: "70dp",
        width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
        borderColor: "#000000",
        borderWidth: "1dp",
        left: "8dp",
        right: "8dp"
    }
```

And my Controller (.js)

```
var counter=0;
function doClick() { 
  counter++;

  var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Address " + counter + " :"
  });
  var textField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    height: "70dp",
    width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    borderColor: "#000000",
    borderWidth: "1dp",
    top: "5dp",
    right: "8dp",
    left: "8dp"
  });

  $.innerContent.add(label);
  $.innerContent.add(textField);
}

$.index.open();
```

[The scroll views does not scroll, or if I already set 3 or four inputs it scroll only to the point where the fourth input was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1ZkN.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to do is to move your styling from `.xml` to `.tss` to increase overview

Try to set your `ScrollView` height to `Ti.UI.SIZE` then set `layout` to `vertical` and after that on your `click` function you add the new view at `top: '5%', bottom: '5%'`

but remember... you have an button outside your `ScrollView`, it will goes off screen when your `ScrollView` increase height

Comment: Well I've found a lot of errors in my code, I guess I need to clean it up and edit to have a better result. Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to change the scrollView height, but the scrollable area inside that view, since I will be adding more labels and textfields inside it

Comment: so you want to increase the heigh of that view that you will be adding, right?
same thing I guess... make it `height: Ti.UI.SIZE` and `layout: 'vertical'`

Comment: Still no succees, unfortunately, I edited the code to add my .tss file, and the scroll still not working seting the UI size and the layotu vertical.

Comment: Try to add to your `rowLayout` to 
    
    `height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    top: '5dp',
    bottom: '5dp'`

Comment: Now it worked, setting the internal view Ti.UI.SIZE, solved the problem, thank you very much